# Struggling to bridge understanding from Probability Theory to Hypothesis Testing Statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have recently done some Probability Theory and am struggling to come to terms with our new chapter: Statistics. This misunderstanding specifically pertains to hypothesis testing.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},( P_{\vartheta},\vartheta\in\theta))$ be a statistical model

I know that the general idea of a test $F \in \mathcal{F}$ for $H_{0}\subseteq ( P_{\vartheta},\vartheta\in\theta)$ is determining a significance level $\alpha \in [0,1]$ such that $\sup_{P_{\vartheta} \in H_{0}}P_{\vartheta}(F)\leq \alpha$. We set $\alpha$ appropriately low so that so that

$P_{\vartheta}(F)\leq \alpha, \forall P_{\vartheta} \in H_{0}$ is extremely unlikely.

Next, I get confused by the following:

If we observe $\omega \in F$(!) ($1.$Question: Should it not be $\omega \in \mathcal{F}$?) then we should discard $H_{0}$, otherwise $H_{0}$ is kept.

$2.$ Question: Why are we looking at "singletons" $\omega$?

If we, for example are on a continuous probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P_{\vartheta})$ then $P(\{w\})=0\leq \alpha$, so no $H_{0}$ would fit. Or are statistical models simply always discrete, and therefore looking at singletons makes sense?

$3.$ I may be missing some key intuition as to the differences between the Probability Theory and Statistics. Any intuitions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. The notation "$\omega \in \mathcal{F}$" does not make sense.
2. We are looking at a particular outcome from $\Omega$ (e.g. a sample drawn from $P_{\vartheta}$). Based on that outcome we make a decision. Since the likelihood of getting $\omega\in F$ is small, we reject $H_0$ in favor to the alternative.

Comment: @d.k.o. In that case, should we not say $P_{\vartheta}(\omega)\leq \alpha$ rather than $P_{\vartheta}(F)\leq \alpha$? So is the difference between the probability model $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and the statistical model $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P_{\vartheta})$ is that in the probability model $F \in \mathcal{F}$ represents a particular event, while in statistics $F \in \mathcal{F}$ represents taking a sample. This leads me to believe however that all statiscal models are discrete. Is this true?

Comment: $F$ represents an event in both cases.

Comment: @d.k.o. An event in a statistical sense would stand for a sample however, correct?

Comment: Consider again the example below. If $X(\omega)=\omega$, then $X$ is a random variable having the exponential distribution with parameter $\vartheta$. A sample here would correspond to a single realization of $X$, i.e. to a single outcome $\omega$. An example of an event is $\{\omega:X(\omega)>x\}$.

Comment: Also a statistical model is a family of probability measures (indexed by $\vartheta$ in your case) living on the same measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and let
$$
P_{\vartheta}(A):=\int_A \vartheta e^{-\vartheta x}1_{[0,\infty)}(x)dx, \quad \vartheta>0.
$$
We want to test $H_0:\vartheta\ge 1$ against $H_1:\vartheta<1$. Taking $F=(-\ln(1-\alpha),\infty)$, we get $\sup_{\vartheta\ge 1}P_{\vartheta}(F)=\alpha$. So if we observe an outcome $\omega>-\ln(1-\alpha)$, we reject $H_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Last question: did you choose $F$ arbitrarily? Or more generally, will the Test $F$ always be defined, or are we required to choose a suitable $F$?